# How do I arrive at the perturbative expansion of a proper n-vertex from the Effective Action without resorting to Feynman Diagrams?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I am especially interested in the expansion of a 4-vertex which is the sum of 1PI diagrams in the expansion of the 4-point connected correlation function.

Comment: You can just do perturbation theory without drawing diagrams, by taking functional derivatives... What is your question, exactly?

Comment: Can you explain with example of a 4 vertex on how to take functional derivatives and come up with an expansion to 2nd order?

Comment: This is not really insightful, and it's covered in most books on quantum field theory. Have you looked at any of the [standard references](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/book-recommendations)?

Comment: I haven't come across a single book on QFT that explicitly derives the 4-point vertex perturbation expansion. Could you cite the references?

Comment: They may not explicitly carry out your calculation, but the methods are clearly set up in e.g. Ryder, Srednicki.